# SharePoint List Permissions Deleted

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, permissions, custom-list, check-permissions

I was modifying the list permissions, and I accidently removed all the permissions on the list.

Now i am unable to see the list

I have full permissions over the subsite but I the List is now not visible to me.

Would the Site collection administrator be able to see the list?

Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: Those three-click accidents can get you lol.  Like Walrus said below, your SA can fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

A site collection administrator will be able to see the list, and grant any removed premissions.